# How few $(42^\circ,60^\circ,78^\circ)$ triangles can a regular hexagon be divided into?

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, puzzle, tiling

While working on an answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3972098/how-few-42-circ-60-circ-78-circ-triangles-can-an-equilateral-triangle-be) excellent post by Edward H. on dissections of an equilateral triangle into similar triangles with angles of $42^\circ, 60^\circ,$ and $78^\circ$, I wondered about a related question: what if we instead try to tile a regular hexagon?

Obviously, any solution for the triangle with $k$ tiles gives a solution of size $6k$. However, we can do much better than this.

At the moment, the best solution I know of makes uses of a shape first discovered by Anders Kaseorg while working on the triangular case, namely that of a $60^\circ-120^\circ$ rhombus constructed from 72 tiles:

[image]

Putting three of these parallelograms together yields a hexagon with $\textbf{216}$ triangles.

However, I think it may well be possible to do substantially better than this. I tried a few methods and haven't yet been able to beat $216$, but just to demonstrate that arrangements of similar size can be achieved with more asymmetric configurations, here is a $274$-triangle arrangement I found:

[image]

It seems quite plausible to me that more clever arrangements of triangles could get below $216$, perhaps substantially so.

I highly recommend reading [the previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3972098/how-few-42-circ-60-circ-78-circ-triangles-can-an-equilateral-triangle-be) and its answers for useful background information and construction strategies before embarking on this problem.

Comment: Are you trying to maximize or minimize the amount of triangles? I assume it’s minimize, but I thought I’d ask.

Comment: Minimize, hence “how few” in the title. It’s trivial to get unbounded numbers of triangles if you have a single valid solution.